# Laravel nova Trends with count all value

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Starting with Laravel Trends and i'm able to display a chart like the following

[image]

following the documentation

```
return $this->countByDays($request, User::class)
        ->showLatestValue();
```

Is it possible to show the sum of all users registered in that period instead of the current value?
Keep the daily graph, but for example instead of 6 would show something like 50.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [showSumValue](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#showing-the-sum-of-values)

```
return $this->countByDays($request, User::class)
        ->showSumValue();
```

Comment: thanks, already tried that and returns a weird
`Call to undefined method Laravel\Nova\Metrics\TrendResult::showSumValue()`

perhaps i'm using an outdated version?

Comment: Possible. What nova version are you using ? The function introduced in [v3.8.0](https://nova.laravel.com/releases/3.8.0)